Render block content with pug doesn't work
I'm face off an issue with Pug engine template. I can't inject the content of a Pug file into my layout, nothing is render! I have a home.pug which extends layout.pug, these two files are in the same folder. I specify that both includes work prefectly.
Any help will be appreciate :)
layout.pug
doctype html
html(lang="fr")
  head
    meta(charset="UTF-8")
    meta(name="viewport", content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0")
    link(rel="stylesheet", href="assets/css/main.css")
    script(src="https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@1.9.10")
    title Blog

  body

    block header
      include ../includes/header

    block appContent

    block footer
      include ../includes/footer

home.pug
extends ./layout

block appContent
  main
    p Hello

NodeJS v20.10.0
Express 4.18.12
Pug 3.0.2

I don't think the issue is within the code you've provided. It might be an issue with the way express or router is configured.
